# Where does xhost store the allowed network addresses?

Tags: linux, xserver

Where does xhost store the allowed network addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xhost` simply calls [`XAddHost` etc.](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XAddHost.3.html), which manipulates a list held by the server.  See [`xhost/xhost.c`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xhost/tree/xhost.c) for the client-side and [`xserver/os/access.c`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/os/access.c) for the server-side.

You [really should](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xauth.html) try to use [`xauth`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xauth.1.html) instead of [`xhost`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xhost.1.html) if possible.  It keeps a list of permissible keys which can be used on a per-user, per-client basis instead of relying on just hostname (spoofable in an unfriendly environment).

Answer (score 5):

I think the addresses are stored inside the xserver.

`xhost` without any arguments should print out the current allowed list.

Comment: It does not print out a list of authorized hostnames on my Mac Big Sur,

Comment: Yes, it prints the list. But where does it store it? Memory only, no files?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man xhost | grep -A 2 FILES
FILES
       /etc/X*.hosts
```

So, I'd take a look in /etc for a file matching that pattern.

The more general lesson here: many commands that use certain files during their operation, will document these files on their manual pages. So, it's a good idea when one wonders something like this, to check the manual. The FILES section is often at the bottom, so a quick "man whatever" followed by ">" (`less` command to go to the end of the file) will often reveal what you're looking for.

Comment: None of those files exist on my system - but I think xhost would still work.

Comment: I got the message "non-network local connections being added to access control list" but there is no /etc/X*.hosts. Therefore I conclude the mystery remains.